# Datetime is being saved as String instead of DateTime object in Laravel MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, laravel-9

I am using Laravel's [Jenseggers MongoDB](https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB) package.

This is my model:-

```
namespace App\Models;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;

use Moloquent, Globals;

class Venue extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $collection = 'venues';
    protected $dates      = array(
                                    'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at',
                                    'created_date', 'modified_date', 'approved_by_admin_at'
                                );

    protected $casts      = array(
                                    'created_at'           => 'datetime', 
                                    'updated_at'           => 'datetime' , 
                                    'deleted_at'           => 'datetime' ,
                                    'created_date'         => 'datetime', 
                                    'modified_date'        => 'datetime',
                                    'approved_by_admin_at' => 'datetime'
                                );

    public function setAttribute($key, $value) {
        $this->attributes[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function venueCreator()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\User', '_id', 'created_by');
    }

    public function venuePartner()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\User', '_id', 'partner_id');
    }
}
```

However, in MongoDB the date time field is being saved as String.

[image]